# SSBU versus SSB on the Wii - Stamina mode and the final KO

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate, super-smash-bros-brawl

Super Smash Bros. Ultimate for the Nintendo switch has been amazing so far, but the one thing I enjoyed more with Super Smash Bros. Brawl is the stamina mode! I loved the fact that after the player was KO’ed their body would stay on the map and not just explode and disappear right away. Is there anyway to change this in the settings, so they don’t just explode?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no way to change this that I am aware of after checking the settings. You could maybe try modding your switch, but that's pretty risky and a lot of work for a small aesthetic.